# Connect Android Smartphone via Remote Desktop

Tags: android, adb, vpn, remote-desktop

I'm trying to connect my Android smartphone to my computer at work via Remote Deskop and a VPN running on a laptop.

I've tried to enable the USB remote FX and I'm using adb on both machine, but I can't make it work.

I'm lauching this command on the laptop :

```
adb -a -P <PORT_NUMBER> nodaemon server
```

And this command on the remote computer :

```
adb -H <REMOTE_IP> -P <PORT_NUMBER> devices
```

But the result is always :

```
 * cannot start server on remote host
adb.exe: failed to check server version: cannot connect to daemon at tcp:l65572:5037: cannot connect to l65572:5037: Une tentative de connexion a échoué car le parti connecté n’a pas répondu convenablement au-delà d’une certaine durée ou une connexion établie a échoué car l’hôte de connexion n’a pas répondu. (10060)
```

And IntelliJ never recongnize the smartphone.

Does anybody has anidea of what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks.